# Unable to curl anything on my Mac curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: networking, macos, curl, homebrew

All of the sudden I can't curl or run `brew` at all. I don't have any proxies enabled and I'm just running my personal mac on my home network. How can I debug/fix this issue?

```
scutil -r google.com            ✔  22:33:48
Reachable
```

```
curl google.com                 ✔  22:34:56
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

```
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
==> Downloading https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-portable-ruby/releases/download/2.6.3_2/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz

curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Error: Failed to download https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable-ruby/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-portable-ruby/releases/download/2.6.3_2/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz!

Do not file an issue on GitHub about this; you will need to figure out for
yourself what issue with your internet connection restricts your access to
both Bintray (used for Homebrew bottles/binary packages) and GitHub
(used for Homebrew updates).
Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby (and your system version is too old)!
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem. My Mac version is Catalina. I had to install the latest version of curl via Homebrew as a last resort and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Get more verbose output by using the option `-v`:

```
curl -v google.com
```

This should help you to track down the problem.

Comment: This didn't help. I should've mentioned I did this. However, upgrading to big sur did fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged this pretty heavily. Watched outbound traffic in lulu, analyzed network logs and verbose output from curl. Not sure why this was failing. Brew was failing as well. I upgraded to Big Sur and everything is fixed.